# Translate API JSON to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

The API I am connecting to has the following JSON reponse (as per their docs):

```json
{
  "total_results": 0,
  "page_size": 0,
  "page_number": 0,
  "offers": [
    {
      "tsin_id": 0,
      "offer_id": 0,
      "sku": "string",
      "barcode": "string",
      "product_label_number": "string",
      "selling_price": 0,
      "rrp": 0,
      "leadtime_days": 0,
      "leadtime_stock": [
        {
          "merchant_warehouse": {
            "warehouse_id": 0,
            "name": "string"
          },
          "quantity_available": 0
        }
      ],
      "status": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "offer_url": "string",
      "stock_cover": [
        {
          "warehouse_id": 0,
          "stock_cover_days": 0
        }
      ],
      "sales_units": [
        {
          "warehouse_id": 0,
          "sales_units": 0
        }
      ],
      "discount": "string",
      "discount_shown": true,
      "storage_fee_eligible": true,
      "date_created": "string",
      "stock_at_takealot_total": 0,
      "stock_at_takealot": [
        {
          "warehouse": {
            "warehouse_id": 0,
            "name": "string"
          },
          "quantity_available": 0
        }
      ],
      "stock_on_way": [
        {
          "warehouse": {
            "warehouse_id": 0,
            "name": "string"
          },
          "quantity_available": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My current code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests as rq
import json
from datetime import datetime

# API information
url = "https://seller-api.takealot.com/v2"
endpoint = "/offers?"
api_key = "Key xyz"

header = {
        'Authorization': api_key
}

full_url = url + endpoint
    
response = rq.get(full_url, headers=header)
    
# convert to dataframe
data = response.text
info = json.loads(data)

df = json_normalize(info["offers"])

# end time
print(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

This returns mostly correct, but columns like `leadtime_stock` don't return correctly. For example, if I print out `tsin_id` I get:

```py
print(df['tsin_id'].head())

0    74215970
1    74759079
2    44290949
3    48140749
4    74824209
Name: tsin_id, dtype: int64
```

But for `leadtime_stock` I get:

```py
print(df['leadtime_stock'].head())

0    [{'merchant_warehouse': {'warehouse_id': 13167...
1    [{'merchant_warehouse': {'warehouse_id': 13167...
2    [{'merchant_warehouse': {'warehouse_id': 13167...
3    [{'merchant_warehouse': {'warehouse_id': 13167...
4    [{'merchant_warehouse': {'warehouse_id': 13167...
Name: leadtime_stock, dtype: object
```

Is there an easy way to convert the columns like `leadtime_stock`, `stock_at_takealot`, `stock_on_way` into the same `df` at the same time, or after the first normalize?

**EDIT**

Required dataframe (as an example) I am after will be in the format:

```
"tsin_id" | "offer_id" | "sku" | "barcode" | "product_label_number" | "selling_price" | "rrp" | "leadtime_days" | "leadtime_stock" | "merchant_warehouse" | "warehouse_id" | "name" | "quantity available"
```

Comment: kindly post the output of ``info = json.loads(data)`` as the source data instead, the output will be a python data structure (the shared data has `true`, python has `True` instead). Also, share your expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy I am not able to post `info` because that holds sensitive information. I have updated around the columns I wish to see for the `df`. Currently, as an example, `leadtime_stock` returns the sub fields as one string (in json format), but I wish to get each field out into the same `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `json_normalize`, pass `leadtime_stock` as `record_path`, and the keys surrounding `leadtime_stock` to `meta` (these parameters are noted in the docs) :

```
pd.json_normalize(data['offers'], 'leadtime_stock', ['tsin_id','offer_id',
                                                     'sku', 'barcode', 
                                                    'product_label_number', 
                                                    'selling_price', 'rrp', 
                                                    'leadtime_days'])
```